# Asp.net C# How to redirect to another page if the current page has query string

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am stucked here. I have  page and opened it via request.query string. Hence called `products.aspx?Id=483`.

So my question is how am I going to redirect from this page to a page that still requires variable to be passed in, in this case the page `details.aspx?Id=56`

It fails to do so. How am I going to do this guys. Any help I will appreciate.

Comment: How did you try to redirect? Please [edit] some code into your post

Comment: Please add some code.

Comment: "It fails to do so" - never just say something doesn't work. Give details. Did it not redirect? Did it redirect but lose your querystring parameter? Did it throw an exception? Did it not compile? There are so many possible things with "fails to do so" that we can't hope to begin guessing where you went wrong. There is nothing hard about redirecting to a page with a querystring so the problem is not with what you are trying to do but with how you are doing it and you haven't shown us that.

Answer (score 1):

By using the `Request.QueryString` property on your `HttpContext` and using `Response.Redirect`

For example:

```
string id = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["id"];
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(id)) {
    Response.Redirect("/some-new-page.aspx");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Answer to pass the value you need to code it like this: **+ IdOrHiddenField1.value);**

```
// Your new value is passed here to the next page after the plus sign
Response.Redirect("newPage.aspx?id=" + IdOrHiddenField1.value);
```

There are **two ways** you can do this,

1. `Response.Redirect`: The Redirect method of the Response object
   provides a way to implement client-side redirection. `Response.Redirect("http://www.yourwebpage.com");`
2. `Server.Transfer`: The Transfer method of the Server object performs
   redirection using the server and avoiding HTTP requests. `Server.Transfer("/myPageWithString.aspx");`

---

```
Response.BufferOutput = true;
string id = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["id"];
//check for empty string
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(id)) {
    Response.Redirect("/myPageWithString.aspx?id=" + IdOrHiddenField1.value);
}
else if (Parse.Int.... == "some blah...")
{
    Response.Redirect("/myPageWithString.aspx?id=" + IdOrHiddenField1.value);
}
```